# Relationship between Hausdorff dimension and covering number

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, metric-spaces, hausdorff-dimension, hausdorff-measure

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and recall that the [$\epsilon$-external covering number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_number) $\mathcal{N}^{\epsilon}(X)$ of $X$ is defined by:
$$
\mathcal{N}^{\epsilon}(X) := \inf\left\{
N\in \mathbb{N}_+:\ (\exists x_1,\dots,x_n\in X)\, X\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^N B_{\epsilon}(x_n)
\right\},
$$
where, for any $x \in X$ and $0<\epsilon$ we denote $B_{\epsilon}(x):=\left\{z \in X:\, d(z,x)<\epsilon\right\}$.

I'm interested in identifying a condition on $X$ guaranteeing that there is some $0<r$ and some $0<c$ such that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\boldsymbol{(1)}\qquad &\mathcal{N}^{\epsilon}(X)\leq \kappa \epsilon^r.
\end{aligned}
$$

A prior, **(1)** seems closely related to the idea of *Ahlfors $r$-regularity*, i.e.: the existence of $0<c_1,c_2$ such that the $r$-Hausdorff measure of any $\epsilon$-Ball in $X$ satisfies
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\boldsymbol{(2)}\qquad &c_1 \epsilon^r \leq \mathcal{H}(B_{\epsilon}(x)) \leq c_2 \epsilon^r.
\end{aligned}
$$

However, for **(1)** and **(2)** to be related in the way I want, I would need to answer:

> For which (compact) metric spaces $X$ does there exist a universal constant $0<C$ not depending on $X$ such that:
> $$ \mathcal{N}^{\epsilon}(X)\leq  C \inf_{x \in X}\mathcal{H}(B_{\epsilon}(x))?$$

Comment: In (1), you wrote $\epsilon$ while you should rather write $1/\epsilon$. This affects your final question, and there might be seveal way to correct it. Then first thing that comes to mind is the relation between Minkowski and Hausdorff dimension, how much have you looked into that?